# OS X 10.8, unsigned application: reset open confirmation

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

When I try to open an unsigned application by double clicking it in OS X 10.8's Finder, it rejects it. When I right-click the application and select Open, it shows a confirmation dialog. When confirming this with "Open", I can open the application the next time.

**How I can reset this behavior, so OS X 10.8 will again reject to double-click this application?**

I need this to test our application in a default environment without having to reinstall a backup.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development.

Answer (score 5):

You can add it using `xattr` from a command prompt, for example to indicate it was downloaded by Safari and have it quarantined as such, just do;

```
xattr -w com.apple.quarantine "0000;4b3a40d0;Safari;|com.apple.Safari" <path to file>;
```